# Unable to load new Page using window.location from java code

Tags: javascript, spring, javascript-engine

I have one interceptor, in which I hv to redirect to main Page if session is invalid.
I want to use window.location for same, but giving error.

My Interceptor is :

```
@Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        if ((null == request.getSession(false))
                || (null == request.getSession(false).getAttribute(
                        "user"))) {
            System.out.println("user logged out...");
            ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
            ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

            engine.eval("window.location='logout.do'");
        return false;
        }
        return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
    }
```

Error :

```
   javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "window" is not defined. (<Unknown source>#1) in <Unknown source> at line number 1
        at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(RhinoScriptEngine.java:110)
        at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(RhinoScriptEngine.java:124)
        at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:247)
        at com.snstech.mocktest.util.MyInterceptor.preHandle(MyInterceptor.java:23)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:761)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:300)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Or is their any other way to do the same...

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ScriptEngineManager` runs the script on server side. `window` is a client-side object, you can't access it from server.

You can send a redirect if you want to do that, see [HttpServletResponse sendRedirect permanent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034149/httpservletresponse-sendredirect-permanent)

Comment: hey thankx for explanation... solved problem by using code in interceptor: PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();out.println("<html><head><script>window.location.href=\"logout.do\";</script></head><body/></html>");

Answer (score 0):

I think that cannot be done, I mean, using JS from Java to redirect to  a page. Anyway, it doesn't make any sense.

You should change the strategy. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999829/redirect-to-another-action-in-an-interceptor-in-struts-2), you can find a way to to id with Struts and [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-handler-interceptors-example/) for Spring. And if you are interested in more solutions, ask Google.